# Issue with Masonry Column Shift layout in isotope plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

My divs change height (to display an initially hidden submit button) when the user focuses the cursor on a Post Comment input box.  When a div's height changes, I want items only in that column to shift to accomodate the height change. And I was pleased to find out that the jquery isotope plugin had a feature for that: masonryColumnShift

I've been following this article here http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html, but my items don't display at all if I set my layout to masonryColumnShift.
Works fine when my layout is set to 'masonry'.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="Container">       
         <div class="item">   
              ...
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(#Container).isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'masonryColumnShift'
});
```

CSS:

```
    #main
    {    
        clear:both;
        padding:40px; 
    }

    #Container
    {
    }



.item
{
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  float:left;  
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  padding:15px;
  ...
}
```

If I have it this way, it works:

```
 $(#Container).isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.  Supposed to add some script to get this to work. Here it is:

```
// -------------------------- Masonry Column Shift -------------------------- //

// custom layout mode
$.Isotope.prototype._masonryColumnShiftReset = function () {
    // layout-specific props
    var props = this.masonryColumnShift = {
        columnBricks: []
    };
    // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again
    this._getSegments();
    var i = props.cols;
    props.colYs = [];
    while (i--) {
        props.colYs.push(0);
        // push an array, for bricks in each column
        props.columnBricks.push([])
    }
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryColumnShiftLayout = function ($elems) {
    var instance = this,
    props = instance.masonryColumnShift;
    $elems.each(function () {
        var $brick = $(this);
        var setY = props.colYs;

        // get the minimum Y value from the columns
        var minimumY = Math.min.apply(Math, setY),
      shortCol = 0;

        // Find index of short column, the first from the left
        for (var i = 0, len = setY.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (setY[i] === minimumY) {
                shortCol = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // position the brick
        var x = props.columnWidth * shortCol,
      y = minimumY;
        instance._pushPosition($brick, x, y);
        // keep track of columnIndex
        $.data(this, 'masonryColumnIndex', i);
        props.columnBricks[i].push(this);

        // apply setHeight to necessary columns
        var setHeight = minimumY + $brick.outerHeight(true),
      setSpan = props.cols + 1 - len;
        for (i = 0; i < setSpan; i++) {
            props.colYs[shortCol + i] = setHeight;
        }

    });
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryColumnShiftGetContainerSize = function () {
    var containerHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, this.masonryColumnShift.colYs);
    return { height: containerHeight };
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryColumnShiftResizeChanged = function () {
    return this._checkIfSegmentsChanged();
};

$.Isotope.prototype.shiftColumnOfItem = function (itemElem, callback) {

    var columnIndex = $.data(itemElem, 'masonryColumnIndex');

    // don't proceed if no columnIndex
    if (!isFinite(columnIndex)) {
        return;
    }

    var props = this.masonryColumnShift;
    var columnBricks = props.columnBricks[columnIndex];
    var $brick;
    var x = props.columnWidth * columnIndex;
    var y = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = columnBricks.length; i < len; i++) {
        $brick = $(columnBricks[i]);
        this._pushPosition($brick, x, y);
        y += $brick.outerHeight(true);
    }

    // set the size of the container
    if (this.options.resizesContainer) {
        var containerStyle = this._masonryColumnShiftGetContainerSize();
        containerStyle.height = Math.max(y, containerStyle.height);
        this.styleQueue.push({ $el: this.element, style: containerStyle });
    }

    this._processStyleQueue($(columnBricks), callback)

};
```

Comment: @parker.sikand https://github.com/desandro/isotope/blob/master/_posts/custom-layout-modes/2012-01-03-masonry-column-shift.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. I also found that you can just rip this code from the page source at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html